# Construct Pandas DataFrame from dictionary in form {index: list of row values}

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I've managed to do this using:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
                    0: [50, 45, 00, 00], 
                    1: [53, 48, 00, 00],
                    2: [56, 53, 00, 00],
                    3: [54, 49, 00, 00],
                    4: [53, 48, 00, 00],
                    5: [50, 45, 00, 00]
                    }, orient='index'
                    )
```

Done like this, the constructor looks just like the DataFrame making it easy to read/edit:

```
>>> dft
    0   1   2   3
0   50  45  0   0
1   53  48  0   0
2   56  53  0   0
3   54  49  0   0
4   53  48  0   0
5   50  45  0   0
```

But the [DataFrame.from_dict constructor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_dict) doesn't have a columns parameter, so giving the columns sensible names takes an additional step:

```
dft.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

This seems clunky for such a handy (e.g. for unit tests) way to initialise DataFrames.

So I wonder: is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternatively you could use `DataFrame.from_items()` to construct the DataFrame from your dictionary; this allows you to pass in the column names at the same time.

For example, if `d` is your dictionary:

```
d = {0: [50, 45, 0, 0],
     1: [53, 48, 0, 0],
     2: [56, 53, 0, 0],
     3: [54, 49, 0, 0],
     4: [53, 48, 0, 0],
     5: [50, 45, 0, 0]}
```

The data is `d.items()` and the orient is again `'index'`. The dictionary keys become the index values:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_items(d.items(), 
                            orient='index', 
                            columns=['A','B','C','D'])
    A   B  C  D
0  50  45  0  0
1  53  48  0  0
2  56  53  0  0
3  54  49  0  0
4  53  48  0  0
5  50  45  0  0
```

In Python 2 you can use `d.iteritems()` to yield the contents of the dictionary to avoid creating another list in memory.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do that is the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
0: {"A":50, "B":40},
1: {"A":51, "B":30}}, orient='index')
```

However, for quick test initialization I would probably prefer your way + then setting the columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
x=pd.DataFrame({0:[50,45],1:[53,48],2:[56,53]}, index=["A","B"]).transpose()
```

But it's still odd as you are specifying the standard index as keys for your dictionary.

Why not directly

```
x = pd.DataFrame({"A":[50,53,56],"B":...})
```

Comment: "Why not directly x = pd.DataFrame({"A":[50,53,56],"B":...})"? Just to keep the numbers in the initialisation in the same positions as the df, as the question mentions...

Comment: The standard index keys are just placeholders, to keep the example simple. Probably I'll need to use datetime objects.